# Add custom alias to .zshrc

Tags: zsh

I can't seem to run these two scripts through zsh. Any ideas?

(In .zshrc)

```
# hidden files
alias show= 'bash /usr/local/bin/show.sh'
alias hide= 'bash /usr/local/bin/hide.sh'
```

Comment: Remove the space after `=`?

Comment: Yup. That worked... Thanks. Add as answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Remove the space character after the `=` character in the alias declaration:

```
# hidden files
alias show='bash /usr/local/bin/show.sh'
alias hide='bash /usr/local/bin/hide.sh'
```

Comment: how come my additions to the .zshrc file are returning commands not found
# alias runserver='http_proxy='localhost:4140' manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:12345'
# alias venv='source venv/bin/activate'